# Is there a way to get total items using ApiPlatform Pagination?

Tags: symfony, pagination, bootstrap-vue, api-platform.com

I'm trying to paginate a table client-side using bootstrap-vue. The api resource i'm trying to paginate actually counts 44 items.

The bootstrap-vue pagination component expects a total-row prop in order to get total pages number (based on items per page) the `/resource` `GET` response return `hydra:totalItems: 15`

15 is actually the default itemsPerPage i have in App/config/packages/api_platform.yaml configuration, which is the following:

```
collection:
exists_parameter_name: 'exists'
order: 'DESC'
order_parameter_name: 'order'
pagination:
  enabled: true
  partial: true
  client_enabled: true
  client_items_per_page: true
  client_partial: true
  items_per_page: 15
  maximum_items_per_page: 100
  page_parameter_name: 'page'
  enabled_parameter_name: 'pagination'
  items_per_page_parameter_name: 'itemsPerPage'
  partial_parameter_name: 'partial'
```

I get the same result both with partial=true/false and ?itemsPerPage=x.
The pagination itself is working: if i call for `?page=1` or `?page=2` i get correct items but `hydra:totalItems` always refers to items returned based on itemsPerPage param.

Also, according to [ApiPlatform docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/) i should also receive a `hydra:view` object with infos on next, prev and last item just enabling pagination on server with its defaults but it's not in the response.

Is there a way to receive paginated collections AND a total?
Current config:
ApiPlatform v. 1.2.2
Symfony 5.1

Comment: With api platform 2.6 i do get the total number of rows in the query result independent from pagination. Maybe you can update api platform? [The releases page](https://api-platform.com/docs/extra/releases/) says "Older versions (1.x, 2.0...) are not maintained. If you still use them, you must upgrade as soon as possible."

Comment: you should get the hydra:view object if your api returns jsonld. If it does is a matter of your configuration of formats you have allowed to return (api_platform.yaml) and you must use the correct mime_type in your request

Answer (score 0):

I see this question more as a business logic than as an API Platform feature

I believe that the simplest way is to implement a query in the entity's object repository that counts the total number of records and returns to a property of your entity with a getter.

See how to achieve this with Symfony docs [Querying for Objects: The Repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository)

Comment: That was my first idea, however with this approach i would get a totalitems field inside every object, which is also valid; but i need it to be outside

Comment: Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) maybe is your solution https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/